# PowerShell to batch package SP2010 projects from VS2010

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, package, wsp

anyone know of PowerShell to batch "package" up solutions, each containing 1-2 projects, to individual WSP files for manual (read: PowerShell-ed) deployment to a remote SP2010 server?

Is there a better methodology?

Answer (score 2):

Option A.  Using Powershell why not just call msbuild on each project:

```
$projectDirectory = "C:\..\MyProject.proj"
$buildDirectory = "C:\..\MyOutputDirectory"
Invoke-Expression "msbuild.exe /t:Package $projectDirectory /p:OutputPath=$buildDirectory"
```

Option B.  You could create a single solution with all the projects that is only used for the build.  Then download the [CKSDev](http://cksdev.codeplex.com/) tools.  The tools will add an option in visual studio on the solution to "Package All SharePoint Projects (CKSDev").

[image]